# WPF Binding from Parent Template through Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Info

I have two classes.

A `Question` class contains: `IEnumerable<Answer>` Answers and `string` Justification.

An `Answer` class contains: `string` AnswerType and `bool` JustificationRequired.

Note: I am showing minimal code for the issue.

### Problem

I am using WPF. To make things modular, we are using `Styles` and `DataTemplates` I am trying to bind a `TextBox` `Visibility` in the Question.xaml to the `Answer` `JustificationRequired` property which is in the AnswerRadio.xaml that is triggered by a `Style`.

### Code

Question:

```
public class Question : IQuestion
{
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers;
    public string Justification;
}
```

Answer:

```
class Answer : IAnswer
{
    public string AnswerType;
    public string JustificationRequired;
}
```

Question.xaml:

```
<ContentControl
    x:Name="AnswerControl"
    Style="{StaticResource AnswerTypeSelector}" />

<TextBox
    x:Name="txtJustification"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Style, ElementName=AnswerControl, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter}}"
    Text="{Binding Justification}" />
```

AnswerTypeSelector.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Templates/AnswerRadio.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="AnswerTypeSelector" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerType}" Value="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource AnswerRadioControl}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

AnswerRadio.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="AnswerRadioItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <RadioButton x:Name="rbAnswer"
                        Content="{Binding Text}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource {x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="AnswerRadioControl" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox
        x:Name="lstQuestionRadioItem"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AnswerRadioItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnswer}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Similarly to the AnswerRadioItem `Style` we can use a RelativeResource Ancestoral binding and bind to the calling `ContentControl` then bind to it's `[Tag][1]` property.

AnswerRadio.xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AnswerRadioControl" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox
        x:Name="lstQuestionRadioItem"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AnswerRadioItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl, Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1}}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then in the Question.xaml we can change the `TextBox` `Visibility` to look at that `ContentControl.Tag` property.

We also need to ensure that there is a FallbackValue as this will not trigger binding at runtime.

Question.xaml:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="txtJustification"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Tag.JustificationRequired, ElementName=AnswerControl, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
    Text="{Binding Justification}" />
```

Comment: I think adding a "SelectedAnswer" property to the Question class would make the solution cleaner. If you don't want to "pollute" your model class with such a property, then consider using a View Model (see MVVM pattern)